# In ZF2, how can I register a custom Feed Reader extension?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to register a **`Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader extension`** for working with **Media RSS**.
I followed the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.feed.reader.html#writing-zend-feed-reader-reader-extensions), however I couldn't even get the extension to register.

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Feed\Reader\StandaloneExtensionManager::setInvokableClass() in ...

This is how I call the function:

```
if (!Reader::isRegistered('MrssService')) {
        $extensions = \Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader::getExtensionManager();
        $extensions->setInvokableClass('MrssService', 'Service\MrssService');
        Reader::registerExtension('MrssService');
    }
```

It seems that **`setInvokableClass()`** doesn't even exist for the object returned by **`Reader::getExtensionManager()`**.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `zend-feed` >= v2.6, there is another way to create custom extensions.

```
$extensions = new \Zend\Feed\Reader\ExtensionPluginManager();
$extensions->setInvokableClass('MrssService', 'Service\MrssService');
Reader::setExtensionManager(new \Zend\Feed\Reader\ExtensionManager($extensions));
Reader::registerExtension('MrssService');
```

BUT actually (v2.7) there is a little problem, that I reported here: https://github.com/zendframework/zend-feed/issues/29

When it will be solved, I will remove this notice on this post.
Meanwhile, if you want to use it, you can just fork and make the edit that I suggested in that Issue.

Comment: Great man! Unfortunately, the project I worked on has already went to grave some time ago :( but I hope others will benefit from this :). It was surprising for me there was no mrss extension on GitHub...